# iCloud sync functionality + Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: sync, mobileme, icloud

With yesterday’s rollout of iCloud, it seems those of us who refuse to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) are left in the dust as far as it goes with calendar/contact syncing.

I have had a MobileMe account for years. I use it to sync my calendars, contacts and email between iPhone/iMac/MacBook Pro.

I am *not* upgrading to Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion).

With the iCloud transition, it seems I’m only able to access my MobileMe email, but my calendars and contacts have stopped syncing.

Has anyone been able to get sync working with iCloud contacts/calendars under Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)?

If not, what are some viable options for a seamless, background sync of calendars and contacts between my various devices?

Comment: Google account sync is probably your best bet, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I have iCal in Snow Leopard syncing to iCloud.
Just add iCloud as a CalDAV account.
Use your iCloud username/password and "p01-caldav.icloud.com" as server address.

I've read that this should be possible with contacts as well, by adding iCloud
as a CardDAV account. But I haven't had any luck with it.

Comment: yeah - im having the same issues. sadly contact sync is what i rely on heavily.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the only way is manually setting it up in iCal and guessing some kind of server id... Not pretty, but it works.

See details here :
[10.6: Add iCloud Calendar in iCal Apps](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111014102515403&msg=15)